# Meaning of “the hatter’s art” in Meyrink's "The Golem"

Tags: meaning, gustav-meyrink, the-golem

Currently reading *The Golem* by Gustav Meyrink and have encountered this sentence:

> “Prokop’s noble specimen of the hatter’s art is tempted to fly away”,
> said Zwakh, pointing to the musician’s huge floppy hat, the broad brim
> of which was beginning to flap like a pair of black wings.”

Can someone explain the meaning of “the hatter’s art”?

Comment: Hatters make hats, and that is their art. The floppy hat was an example.

Comment: Use of a name for a trade or practitioner of a trade with the word _art_ refers to the actions and skills involved. _The art of the blacksmith/farrier/woodcarver/hunter/tracker_, etc; or _the hunter's/blacksmith's .. art_. It's a semipoetic phrase that allows nonce generalizations instead of technical terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's irony... The hat is ***huge*** and ***floppy***, and the speaker ironically attributes its eccentricity to the 'art' of making hats.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/art) defines art as

> ***the making of objects***, images, music, etc. that are beautiful or that express feelings

and

> a skill or special ability.

Another example of ironic use is

> Getting him to go out is quite an ***art*** (= needs special skill).

Answer (score 4):

This use of "art" has nothing to do with the general concept of "art" (as in painting, scupture, music, etc.) It is the art in the meaning of "skill and craftsmanship"

See OED:

1. **Skill in doing something, esp. as the result of knowledge or practice.**

> 1939   Times 21 Aug. 15/4   *There is great art in jack throwing, and the jack should not come to rest at less than 25 yards.*

See also: *"The Art of the Deal"* by Donald Trump · 2016 / *"The Art of War"* by Sun Tzu 5th Century BCE, etc.